# Looking for a simple way to retrieve host name, computer name, and ipv6 using asp or vb6

Tags: jquery, vb6, asp-classic

Is there a simple to use easy way to pull the computer name, host name, and ipv6 ipaddress using vb6, asp, or jQuery?  The reason is because its for logging information for security.

Comment: It would seem odd to log these things for the computer your code is running on, since they will remain the same for long periods of time if not forever.  Are you trying to retrieve these from some remote system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB6 doesn't have a way to do this directly inside the language or the runtime as you would do in .NET, however, Windows has an extensive management interface that can be access through COM.  The Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) is a COM-based interface for doing all sorts of management stuff.  COM automation is incredibly simple in VB6.

I would suggest looking at the VBScripts done by the Microsoft Scripting Guys, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/default.  It should be a relatively simple extercise to port a VBScript to VB6.  Here is the VBScript that does what you want:
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ff7bc830-a67d-434e-9c77-ebe1ff7d6a4d

I don't have VB6 on this machine to get you a perfect code example right now, however,  simply changing the Wscript.Echo calls to Debug.Print you can pretty much run this in VB6.

```
strcomputer = Inputbox("Name of Computer","Computer IP Query") 

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colAdapters = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True") 

n = 1 

For Each objAdapter in colAdapters 
   Debug.Print "Network Adapter " & n 
   Debug.Print "=================" 
   Debug.Print "  Description: " & objAdapter.Description 

   Debug.Print "  Physical (MAC) address: " & objAdapter.MACAddress 
   Debug.Print "  Host name:              " & objAdapter.DNSHostName 

   If Not IsNull(objAdapter.IPAddress) Then 
      For i = 0 To UBound(objAdapter.IPAddress) 
         Debug.Print "  IP address:             " & objAdapter.IPAddress(i) 
      Next 
   End If 

   If Not IsNull(objAdapter.IPSubnet) Then 
      For i = 0 To UBound(objAdapter.IPSubnet) 
         Debug.Print "  Subnet:                 " & objAdapter.IPSubnet(i) 
      Next 
   End If 

   If Not IsNull(objAdapter.DefaultIPGateway) Then 
      For i = 0 To UBound(objAdapter.DefaultIPGateway) 
         Debug.Print "  Default gateway:        " & _ 
             objAdapter.DefaultIPGateway(i) 
      Next 
   End If 

   Debug.Print 
   Debug.Print "  DNS" 
   Debug.Print "  ---" 
   Debug.Print "    DNS servers in search order:" 

   If Not IsNull(objAdapter.DNSServerSearchOrder) Then 
      For i = 0 To UBound(objAdapter.DNSServerSearchOrder) 
         Debug.Print "      " & objAdapter.DNSServerSearchOrder(i) 
      Next 
   End If 

   Debug.Print "    DNS domain: " & objAdapter.DNSDomain 

   If Not IsNull(objAdapter.DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder) Then 
      For i = 0 To UBound(objAdapter.DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder) 
         Debug.Print "    DNS suffix search list: " & _ 
             objAdapter.DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder(i) 
      Next 
   End If 

   Debug.Print 
   Debug.Print "  DHCP" 
   Debug.Print "  ----" 
   Debug.Print "    DHCP enabled:        " & objAdapter.DHCPEnabled 
   Debug.Print "    DHCP server:         " & objAdapter.DHCPServer 

   If Not IsNull(objAdapter.DHCPLeaseObtained) Then 
      utcLeaseObtained = objAdapter.DHCPLeaseObtained 
      strLeaseObtained = WMIDateStringToDate(utcLeaseObtained) 
   Else 
      strLeaseObtained = "" 
   End If 
   Debug.Print "    DHCP lease obtained: " & strLeaseObtained 

   If Not IsNull(objAdapter.DHCPLeaseExpires) Then 
      utcLeaseExpires = objAdapter.DHCPLeaseExpires 
      strLeaseExpires = WMIDateStringToDate(utcLeaseExpires) 
   Else 
      strLeaseExpires = "" 
   End If 
   Debug.Print "    DHCP lease expires:  " & strLeaseExpires 

   Debug.Print 
   Debug.Print "  WINS" 
   Debug.Print "  ----" 
   Debug.Print "    Primary WINS server:   " & objAdapter.WINSPrimaryServer 
   Debug.Print "    Secondary WINS server: " & objAdapter.WINSSecondaryServer 
   Debug.Print 

   n = n + 1 

Next 

Public Function WMIDateStringToDate(utcDate) 
   WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(utcDate, 5, 2)  & "/" & _ 
       Mid(utcDate, 7, 2)  & "/" & _ 
           Left(utcDate, 4)    & " " & _ 
               Mid (utcDate, 9, 2) & ":" & _ 
                   Mid(utcDate, 11, 2) & ":" & _ 
                      Mid(utcDate, 13, 2)) 
End Function
```

Comment: One last thing, I would NOT recommend just pasting this VBScript code in your app.  I am putting this out here as only as a demonstration on what you can do with WMI COM automation.  Your app should have variables declared correctly, error handling and all that good stuff.

Comment: Also consider that WMI might not be installed or running on a given system.